# Omit 0 value points on chart.js radar

Tags: javascript, chart.js

[image]

Is there a way to omit 0 value points on a radar chart from chart.js to prevent the border from collapsing in the center while still showing the axis of the 0 value points?

Attached is a picture of what I'd like to achieve (left is current chart, right is what I'm looking for).

Thank you!

Edit: attached is a minimal reproductible example, a plain chart.js radar chart.

```js
const labels = [
  'O', 'D', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'A', 'P', 'C', 'I', 'F'
];

var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: '01',
    data: [0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2],
  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      r: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          display: false,
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can help you.

Comment: It might be confusing because the value on this axis would be wrong.

Comment: @TechySharnav I've provided a minimal reproductible example, tell me if you need anything else please.

Comment: You can filter the values when you are setting it in the `data` object.

Comment: Sounds like you need to overlay two charts: One just like what you have and one where use filter out the 0s (`data.filter(Boolean)`)

Comment: @TechySharnav Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by filter. I need to still see the axis of the 0 value parameters. In the example the F parameter has a value of 0 so the visual point is omitted and links directly with D, is it possible to do this?

Comment: @Juan Mendes I've attached a new picture to better show what I'm looking for. Visual points with 0 value are omitted but the axis have to still be visible.

Comment: @RamonBosch Yeah, I was trying to find a way to guess what values to interpolate but it's not straight forward. However, @TechySharnav [got the answer by passing nulls instead of zeroes combined with `spanGaps: true`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72953151/227299)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `map` the data array to replace all `0` values with `null` and then set
`spanGaps: true` in the options, which will skip missing data and connect the line to next point.

```js
const labels = [
  'O', 'D', 'M', 'L', 'S', 'A', 'P', 'C', 'I', 'F'
];

var data = {
  labels: labels,
  datasets: [{
    label: '01',
    data: [0, 2, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 2].map(n => n === 0 ? null : n),
  }]
};

const config = {
  type: 'radar',
  data: data,
  options: {
    spanGaps: true,
    scales: {
      r: {
        min: 0,
        max: 3,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 1,
          display: false,
        }
      },
    },
  },
};

const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-KfkfwYDsLkIlwQp6LFnl8zNdLGxu9YAA1QvwINks4PhcElQSvqcyVLLD9aMhXd13uQjoXtEKNosOWaZqXgel0g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```